# There was an error while setting up the configuration plugin option "DBDictionary"

Tags: jpa

In persistence.xml there is a property :

**property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="oracle(StoreCharsAsNumbers=false,supportsSetClob=true,MaxEmbeddedClobSize=-1)"/>**

While fetching data getting below error :

Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.util.ParseException: There was an error while setting up the configuration plugin option "DBDictionary". The plugin was of type "class com.ibm.ws.persistence.jdbc.sql.OracleDictionary". The plugin property "supportsSetClob" had no corresponding setter method or accessible field. The plugin property closely matches "SupportsHaving"; perhaps the property was misspelled. Ensure that your plugin configuration string uses key values that correspond to setter methods in the plugin class. All possible plugin properties are: [AllowsAliasInBulkClause, Array, ArrayTypeName, AsciiStream, AutoAssignClause, AutoAssignSequenceName, AutoAssignTypeName, BatchLimit, BigDecimal, BigInteger, BigintTypeName, BinaryStream, BinaryTypeName, BitLengthFunction, BitTypeName, Blob, BlobBufferSize, BlobObject, BlobTypeName, Boolean, BooleanTypeName, Byte, Bytes, CONS_NAME_AFTER, CONS_NAME_BEFORE, CONS_NAME_MID, Calendar, CastFunction, CatalogSeparator, Char, CharTypeName, CharacterColumnSize, CharacterStream, CheckVersionStrategy, Clob, ClobBufferSize, ClobString, ClobTypeName, ClosePoolSQL, ConcatenateDelimiter, ConcatenateFunction, ConstraintNameMode, CreatePrimaryKeys, CrossJoinClause, CurrentDateFunction, CurrentTimeFunction, CurrentTimestampFunction, Date, DatePrecision, DateTypeName, DecimalTypeName, DefaultBatchLimit, DistinctCountColumnSeparator, DistinctTypeName, Double, DoubleTypeName, DriverVendor, DropTableSQL, FixedSizeTypeNames, Float, FloatTypeName, ForUpdateClause, GetStringVal, IgnoreSQLExceptionOnSetQueryTimeout, InClauseLimit, InitializationSQL, InnerJoinClause, Int, IntegerTypeName, JavaObjectTypeName, JoinSyntax, LastGeneratedKeyQuery, Locale, Long, LongVarbinaryTypeName, LongVarcharTypeName, MaxAutoAssignNameLength, MaxColumnNameLength, MaxConstraintNameLength, MaxEmbeddedBlobSize, MaxEmbeddedClobSize, MaxIndexNameLength, MaxIndexesPerTable, MaxTableNameLength, NativeSequenceType, NextSequenceQuery, Null, NullTypeName, Number, NumericTypeName, Object, Openjpa3GeneratedKeyNames, OtherTypeName, OuterJoinClause, Platform, RangePosition, RealTypeName, Ref, RefTypeName, ReportsSuccessNoInfoOnBatchUpdates, RequiresAliasForSubselect, RequiresAutoCommitForMetaData, RequiresCastForComparisons, RequiresCastForMathFunctions, RequiresConditionForCrossJoin, RequiresSearchStringEscapeForLike, RequiresTargetForDelete, ReservedWords, SCHEMA_CASE_LOWER, SCHEMA_CASE_PRESERVE, SCHEMA_CASE_UPPER, SELECT_HINT, SYNTAX_DATABASE, SYNTAX_SQL92, SYNTAX_TRADITIONAL, SchemaCase, SearchStringEscape, SelectWords, SequenceNameSQL, SequenceSQL, SequenceSchemaSQL, SetStringRightTruncationOn, Short, SimulateLocking, SmallintTypeName, SqlStateCodes, StorageLimitationsFatal, StoreCharsAsNumbers, StoreLargeNumbersAsStrings, String, StringLengthFunction, StructTypeName, SubstringFunctionName, SupportsAlterTableWithAddColumn, SupportsAlterTableWithDropColumn, SupportsAutoAssign, SupportsCascadeDeleteAction, SupportsCascadeUpdateAction, SupportsComments, SupportsCorrelatedSubselect, SupportsDefaultDeleteAction, SupportsDefaultUpdateAction, SupportsDeferredConstraints, SupportsForeignKeys, SupportsHaving, SupportsLockingWithDistinctClause, SupportsLockingWithInnerJoin, SupportsLockingWithMultipleTables, SupportsLockingWithOrderClause, SupportsLockingWithOuterJoin, SupportsLockingWithSelectRange, SupportsModOperator, SupportsMultipleNontransactionalResultSets, SupportsNullDeleteAction, SupportsNullTableForGetColumns, SupportsNullTableForGetImportedKeys, SupportsNullTableForGetIndexInfo, SupportsNullTableForGetPrimaryKeys, SupportsNullUpdateAction, SupportsQueryTimeout, SupportsRestrictDeleteAction, SupportsRestrictUpdateAction, SupportsSchemaForGetColumns, SupportsSchemaForGetTables, SupportsSelectEndIndex, SupportsSelectForUpdate, SupportsSelectStartIndex, SupportsSubselect, SupportsUniqueConstraints, SupportsXMLColumn, SystemSchemas, SystemTables, TableForUpdateClause, TableTypes, Time, TimeTypeName, Timestamp, TimestampTypeName, TinyintTypeName, ToLowerCaseFunction, ToUpperCaseFunction, TrimBothFunction, TrimLeadingFunction, TrimSchemaName, TrimTrailingFunction, Typed, Unknown, UseGetBestRowIdentifierForPrimaryKeys, UseGetBytesForBlobs, UseGetObjectForBlobs, UseGetStringForClobs, UseSchemaName, UseSetBytesForBlobs, UseSetFormOfUseForUnicode, UseSetStringForClobs, UseTriggersForAutoAssign, VENDOR_DATADIRECT, VENDOR_ORACLE, VENDOR_OTHER, ValidationSQL, VarbinaryTypeName, VarcharTypeName, VersionColumnIntegerSyntax, VersionColumnTableSyntax, VersionColumnTimestampSyntax, XmlTypeName, _defaultBatchLimit].

Please suggest.

Comment: Could you try to format the post a little more nicely? We have some cool formatting options here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a openjpa version 2.2.0 or superior just get rid of it.
I mean, get rid of just this part:

```
,supportsSetClob=true
```

Check this out:

http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.2.2/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_2.2.html#jpa_2.2_SupportsSetClob

The doc says it is not needed any more.

*PS: the same should be valid for the IBM's implementation of oracle's DBDictionary.*